# Laravel simplified save data in database by simple function

Tags: php, laravel

As we know, we can save data in database by this code:

```php
$address = new Address();
$address->user_id = $user->id;
$address->title = $request->get('title');
$address->detail = $request->get('detail');
$address->phone = $request->get('phone');
$address->address = $request->get('address');
$address->save();
```

here i want to simplified this action by a function such as `save()` for example:

```php
save(
    class: Address::class,
    fields: [
        'title',
        'detail',
        'phone',
        'address',
        'user_id' => 1,
    ]
);

function save($class, $fields): void
{
    $class = new $class;
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
        if ($key == null) {
            $class->$field = get($field);
        } else {
            $class->$key = $field;
        }
    }
    $class->save();
}

function get(string $key)
{
    return request()->get($key);
}
```

after using `save` method i get incorrect data in `attributes`:

```
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "title" => "aaaaa"
    1 => "detail"
    2 => "phone"
    3 => "address"
    "user_id" => 1
  ]
```

i don't know why in this section my function generate incorrect data with incorrect array keys for that and it should be:

```
  #attributes: array:5 [
    "title"   => "test"
    "detail"  => "test detail"
    "phone"   => "test phone"
    "address" => "test address"
    "user_id" => 1
  ]
```

how can i resolve `save` method to generate above array of data?

Comment: Why don't you use the create function ? no need to loop over the fields, just pass an array of fields

Comment: Why are you recreating the wheel and not using one of the provided methods such as `create` or `update`?

Comment: @Lk77 i want to try by myself

Comment: Well first of, key is never null, even when you don't specify a key, it will have one (0,1,2,3...), so you always end up in the else. The if should be about the type of the key, either int or string

Comment: @Lk77 if `$key` is null, i should get `$field` from `request` otherwise `$field` should be value of key

Comment: $key cannot be null, an array entry always has a value and a key no matter what, if you don't specify one, it will be implied, aka an int, but not null.

Comment: In your code `if ($key == null)` this part never run because in array key should be not `null`

Comment: @Lk77 first of array as `title` and end of array as `user_id` are correct, i don't know why other fields are not correct

Comment: Because they have an actual value it seems. If you want your code to work, you will need to always provide a value, even null; so `fields: ['title'` becomes `fields: ['title'=>null`, and you should replace `$key == null` by `$field == null`

Comment: @JSTECH your comment cause of resolving my problem by using `getType` thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by checking array key by `getType` thanks to [@jstech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14151733/js-tech)

```php
function save($class, $fields): void
{
    $class = new $class;
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
        if (gettype($key) == 'integer') {
            $class->$field = get($field);
        } else {
            $class->$key = $field;
        }
    }
    $class->save();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
new Address([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'title' => $request->title,
    'detail' => $request->detail,
    'phone' => $request->phone,
    'address' => $request->address,
]);
```

Comment: You don't answer the question